# Usb Ports Are Not Working Properly

Tags: usb

I am using a dual boot system. When i was working on windows suddenly my all usb ports stopped working. Then i switched to the ubuntu. It was working well but if I unplug a device and and plug it to any other port, it kills all the ports. I have three ports including one usb 3 and two usb 2 ports.Let the name of the ports be A,B,C .For example, I plug my mouse to the port A then i unplug it.If I plug it to port B or C. It kills all the ports. But putting it back to port A is no problem. Same situtation is valid for B and C too. I use acer v3-571g. Since the ports working well when I do no not unplug them, can I be sure that this problem is about software? If so why I face with similar problems in ubuntu and windows? Does windows and ubuntu uses any common power management system or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu! In order to get more detailed information about your topic, please specify which devices you were using. Was it a mouse, printer or storage devices? In addition, please open a terminal window in ubuntu and enter the following command: `lsusb -v` when you have connected some of your usual devices.

Comment: I use a logitech m185 wireless mouse and a scandisk flash disc.  Both devices working well on other computers. I get a long answer by typing lsusb -v on terminal. What information should i tell you? Thanks for the answer.